# MySQL - how do i assign a value with another value where both of them goes into different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry if my title is wordy and doesn't make sense, but i don't really know how to say this

anyway what I'm trying to say is that I want to assign a value with another value, so that when I put it into the table, I don't have to type them manually. for example I have column named "ItemID" and another named "ItemName". I put data in the itemID column like say, 64123, and then I also put data in the ItemName column (say, "black T-shirt"). how do I make it so when I type in 64123 in the itemID column it automatically puts "black T-shirt" in the itemName column so that I don't have to do them separately every time?

I hope I'm making sense, i tried googling but I couldn't really find anything useful because my English sucks

Comment: can you update the code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question, but here's how you can insert both values at the same time

```
INSERT INTO example(ItemID, ItemName) VALUES (64123, "black T-shirt");
```